# Broken IC UCC28C44?

Tags: integrated-circuit, short-circuit

I'm having some hickups with an providing supply voltage to UCC28C44 PWM controller. I have noticed that when I remove resistor RS7, VDD voltage rises to 18V as I expect. If RS7 is there the voltage is zero so I'm guessing that IC is broken somehow and that it has turned into a short circuit. Does it sound reasonable?

[image: brokenIC]

Comment: You can always replace by a known good and check...

Comment: Replaced it. It was broken. For future reference, a broken IC can turn into a short.